# for loop changes length when changing starting range value

Tags: python, python-3.x

i tried doing the project euler problem nr.4;

first of all, my code stops at 999, 91 for no reason;

but thats not the heart of this question, if u can find the solution to that problem id also like to hear your answer!

but, my problem right now is, that i want the for loops to start later, because i dont wanna wait for all of the iterations till 999:

my code looks like this:

```
    num=0
    rev=0
for a in range(1000):
    for b in range(1000):
        num=a*b
        rev=int(str(num)[::-1])
        if num==rev and num!=0 and rev!=0:
            print(a,b,num,rev)
```

it works ok, but it has 2 problems:

first; when i change range(1000) to range(100,1000) it stops at 995 instead of 999 for no reason.

second: it doesnt get the real answer of 906609:
because it stops at 999, 91 and doesnt find another palindromic number until 1001

so yeah i hope you can help me ty :)

Comment: I think the problem is that when `a` turns to 996 and above, the requirement of `num==rev` is not fulfiled. Thus, it won't be printed.

Comment: Your code doesn't stop at a `b` value of `91`. The combination `991, 91` is just the last matching combination.

Comment: @Matthias you see, i knew that, but 991,91 is not the highest number, because there is 906609, which my code isnt finding, which makes me think my codes also doesnt find other numbers, so now i need to figure out why

Comment: You get the number `906609` for the combination `913, 993` (and `993, 913`). If you want to find the highest multiplied number then you'll have to do some extra work (see answer from @Chrispresso).

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not stop at the largest value it finds, just the last one it finds. Once `a` hits `991`, the last value `b` can be in order to fulfill a palindromic number is `91`.
If you want the largest you need to keep count of the largest value produced like so:

```
max_a, max_b, max_num = 0, 0, 0
for a in range(1000):
    for b in range(1000):
        num=a*b
        rev=int(str(num)[::-1])
        if num==rev and num!=0 and rev!=0:
            if num > max_num:
                max_a, max_b, max_num = a, b, num

print(max_a, max_b, max_num) # 913 993 906609
```

Comment: JFTR: We could speed up the code if we use `for b in range(a, 1000):`. This will avoid duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Ohhh, while trying to ask another question i just found out what i did wrong, my bad, i didnt even think about a combination that doesnt start with 999, thanks!

Comment: This would solve part 2 of my question, but whats with part 1? because that just doesnt make sense to me, why adjusting the range of a for loop would change the output

Comment: Of course changing the range will affect the result! The last combination is `999, 91`. `91` is not included in `range(100, 1000)`.

Comment: @Leno22ß6 it doesn't stop at `995` for no reason. You gave `range(100, 1000)`, which means that `b` is unable to ever be `91`. Because of this, the last value your code will find will be different.

Comment: OHHHH im so stupid haha, thank you for explaining!!

Comment: Looks like an `OutOfCoffeeError`.

Answer (score 0):

```
num=0
rev=0
max_num=0
for a in range(100, 1000):
    for b in range(100, 1000):
        num=a*b
        rev=int(str(num)[::-1])
        if num==rev and num!=0 and rev!=0:

            if num>max_num:
                max_num=num
            print(a,b,num,rev, max_num)
```

did it for me! i just had a brain failure which @Chrispresso fixed! It was even easier than what he suggested! i just had to add a max_num variable! Thanks for your time everyone!